# Attempting to order a dynamically created <ul> or <ol> list with CSS

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm working with another web developer's application and I'm trying to resolve a few issues. I have an unordered list of sizes being output from the framework as followed:

```
<ul id="size-options">
  <li value="2X"> ... </li>
  <li value="S"> ... </li>
  <li value="M"> ... </li>
  <li value="L"> ... </li>
  <li value="XL> ... </li>
```

Before I take a sledge hammer approach and try to solve the ordering with Javascript, I would like to check with the community for a possible  or similar fix. I'm getting varied results from Google. I realize this issue could also be fixed within the query that calls the data but I'm attempting to save that as a last resort. Thank you.

Comment: CSS cannot do this. You need to use JavaScript.

Comment: css is for styling only I don't think it can manipulate the order of dom elements unless you gave each element a class and styled that, but I think you would be better off going the js route if you are keeping changing it at the source to a last resort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is corrupted: `value` attribute for `li` is ***deprecated*** (although supported in HTML5), and it is numeric:

[W3C Lists in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#edef-LI)

> Attribute definitions
>
> `value` = **number** [CN]
>       ***Deprecated***. For `LI` only. This attribute sets the number of the current list item. Note that while the value of this attribute is an
>   integer, the corresponding label may be non-numeric (see the start
>   attribute).

The only exception is

> Thus, when the list item style is uppercase latin letters (A, B, C,
>   ...), start=3 means "C". When the style is lowercase roman numerals,
>   start=3 means "iii", etc.

Comment: If we're going to talk about the markup might I add that it should really be `ol` and an ordered list of values... not a `ul` of mixed up values.

Comment: yeah, that too... first correction the syntax, then the semantic :/